# To prove that $Ran (R^{-1})=Dom(R))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

To prove that $Ran (R^{-1})=Dom(R))$, R is a relation from A to B

Let $ x \in Ran (R^{-1})$. So $ \exists b \in B | (b,a) \in R ^{-1}$. So $ \exists b \in B | (a.b) \in R$. How do i proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ran(R^{-1}) = \{y \mid (x,y)\in R^{-1} \mbox{ for some }x\in B\} = \{y\mid (y,x)\in R\mbox{ for some }x\in B\} =dom(R)$. The first and last equations follow from the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the definitions:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ran}{Ran}x\in\ran(R^{-1})&\!\!\!\iff\exists y\in A: (y,x)\in R^{-1}\\
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{Dom}x\in\dom(R)&\!\!\!\iff\exists y\in A: (x,y)\in R\\
(y,x)\in R^{-1}&\!\!\!\iff (x,y)\in R
\end{array}\right.
$$
and

Comment: You mean to say if two statements are equivalent (both sides) to third one, then they are to each other

Comment: Yes, exactly so.